# How Can I run foreach iteratively?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, iterator, warnings

I get warnings when I run this code, I wanna have 11 rows of result but it comes out only 1 row 
Should I insert for loop? If so, can you guys specify it in the code? 
Also, I have tried `(i in 1:length(alpha))` but it didn't work either.

```
 require(useful)
 iris1<-iris[1:100,]
 acsx<-build.x(Species~ Sepal.Length+ Sepal.Width+ Petal.Length +Petal.Width-
  1,data=iris1,contrasts=FALSE)
 acsy<-build.y(Species~ Sepal.Length+ Sepal.Width+ Petal.Length +Petal.Width-1,data=iris1)
 theFolds<-sample(rep(x=1:5,length.out=nrow(acsx)))
 alphas<-seq(from=0.5, to =1, by=0.05)


 result<-foreach(i=1:length(alphas), .errorhandling="remove",
               .inorder=FALSE, multicombine=TRUE,
               .export=c("acsx","acsy","alphas","theFolds"),
               .packages="glmnet") %dopar%
   {  for(i in 1:length(alphas) )
  print(alphas[i])
  cv.glmnet(x=acsx,y=acsy,family="binomial",nfold=5,foldid=theFolds, alpha=alphas[i])  
   }
```

**Warning message:**

> In e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) :
>     already exporting variable(s): acsx, acsy, alphas, theFolds`

Comment: Your example is not reproducible, making it hard to test.  Please add sample data (or build a model using `iris`) and show all required libraries to run your code.

Comment: First of all, that's a **warning**, not an **error**, so if your code is failing that's not the reason.  All it's saying is that you're repetitively exporting stuff; possibly once per `i` value.

Comment: Thank you for comments. I just edit the code with data, can you let me know how to generate 11 observations?

Answer (score 3):

Your code returns no results because:

1. The `cv.glmnet` fails throws an error:
2. You told `foreach` to suppress the error.

Try this code and then gradually debug:

```
library(foreach)
library(glmnet)
result <- foreach(i = 1:length(alphas), 
                  .errorhandling = "pass", 
                  .inorder = FALSE, 
                  .multicombine = TRUE, 
                  .packages = "glmnet") %do% {
  cv.glmnet(x=acsx, y=acsy, family="multinomial", nfold=5, foldid=theFolds, alpha=alphas[i]) 
}

result
```

---

```
[[1]]
<simpleError: from glmnet Fortran code (error code 8003); Null probability for class 3 < 1.0e-5>

[[2]]
<simpleError: from glmnet Fortran code (error code 8003); Null probability for class 3 < 1.0e-5>

[[3]]
<simpleError: from glmnet Fortran code (error code 8003); Null probability for class 3 < 1.0e-5>
```